# React type error while setting the boolean value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am trying to set a boolean value using a `setEditMode` function but unfortunately, I am encountering with a type error while invoking the component in index.tsx file.

The error is `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type '(editMode: boolean) => void'.ts(2322)`

Here is the [Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-fog-whw42m?file=/src/index.tsx)

The error can be checked in the `index.tsx` file.
Can anybody guide me with the correct path Why is it so and what is the best way to solve it.

Comment: Maybe you need to import `@types/react` (`npm i -D @types/react`)?

Comment: You appear to be passing a boolean (`false`) to a property (`setEditMode`) that expects a function, the error message is relatively clear.

Comment: This is not related as the package is already installed

Comment: @ninja your original sandbox link did not have the types installed... but anyways, as DBS says, you are passing a boolean value, instead of a function that returns a boolean. Also, your `App` does not need to take props. You should have a nested component that takes props passed in from the `App`.

Comment: Okay, got the point. But, can this be done even without passing a function in the setEditMode as it is now. I think in general we would like to just pass the boolean value setEditMode={false}. So, wondering what would be the correct type to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments mentioned you are passing a boolean to a prop that expects a function.
You can avoid that by passing the editMode value instead like so.

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App initialEditMode={false} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

And then for what I believe is the functionality you want you can modify the App.js to be like this

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

interface Props {
  initialEditMode: boolean;
}

    export default function App({ initialEditMode }: Props) {
      const [editMode, setEditMode] = React.useState(initialEditMode);
      const openEditMode = () => {
        setEditMode(true);
      };
      return !editMode && <div onClick={openEditMode}>Edit</div>;
    }
```

This would use the initial edit value from your index file to create a new state. And then clicking on the edit button would update the editMode state to true

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid props in the `App` component. Instead, I would create an `EditableComponent` that takes these props. Just keep track of the state in `App` or a context/store. The internal component can handle local updates to the value.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import EditableComponent from "./EditableComponent";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [editMode, setEditMode] = React.useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("Hello World!");

  return (
    <EditableComponent
      editMode={editMode}
      setEditMode={setEditMode}
      updateValue={setValue}
      value={value}
    />
  );
}
```

The following component takes an edit mode and a value. The component itself updates the local value, and upon saving, will update the value in the `App`. I wrapped the `<input>` in a form so that he <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will trigger the update (if you do not wish to click the button).

I also added a cancel action that reverts the value back to the original.

```js
import * as React from "react";

export type EditableComponentProps = {
  editMode: boolean;
  setEditMode: (editMode: boolean) => void;
  value: string;
  updateValue: (value: string) => void;
};

export default function EditableComponent(props: EditableComponentProps) {
  const { editMode, setEditMode, updateValue, value } = props;

  const [localValue, setLocalValue] = React.useState(value);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLocalValue(value);
  }, [value]);

  const updateLocalValue = React.useCallback(
    (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
      setLocalValue(event.target.value);
    },
    []
  );

  const openEditMode = React.useCallback(() => {
    setEditMode(true);
  }, [setEditMode]);

  const closeEditMode = React.useCallback(
    (e: React.FormEvent) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const form: HTMLFormElement = e.target as HTMLFormElement;
      const data: FormData = new FormData(form);
      const newValue = data.get("localValue")?.toString() ?? "";
      setEditMode(false);
      updateValue(newValue);
    },
    [setEditMode, updateValue]
  );

  const revertValue = React.useCallback(() => {
    setEditMode(false);
    setLocalValue(value);
  }, [setEditMode, value]);

  // Render the "edit"
  if (editMode) {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={closeEditMode}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="localValue"
          value={localValue}
          onInput={updateLocalValue}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Save Changes</button>
        <button type="button" onClick={revertValue}>
          Cancel
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p>{value}</p>
      <button type="button" onClick={openEditMode}>
        Edit
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

---

### Snippet

Here is a working snippet. Note that it's JSX rather than TSX, so types will not be defined, but the principle business logic remains.

```js
const { Fragment, useCallback, useEffect, useState } = React;

const EditableComponent = (props) => {
  const { editMode, setEditMode, updateValue, value } = props;
  const [localValue, setLocalValue] = useState(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLocalValue(value);
  }, [value]);

  const updateLocalValue = useCallback((event) => {
    setLocalValue(event.target.value);
  }, []);

  const openEditMode = useCallback(() => {
    setEditMode(true);
  }, [setEditMode]);

  const closeEditMode = useCallback((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const form = e.target;
    const data = new FormData(form);
    const newValue = data.get("localValue") || "";
    setEditMode(false);
    updateValue(newValue);
  }, [setEditMode, updateValue]);

  const revertValue = useCallback(() => {
    setEditMode(false);
    setLocalValue(value);
  }, [setEditMode, value]);

  // Render the "edit"
  if (editMode) {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={closeEditMode}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="localValue"
          value={localValue}
          onInput={updateLocalValue}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Save Changes</button>
        <button type="button" onClick={revertValue}>
          Cancel
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <p>{value}</p>
      <button type="button" onClick={openEditMode}>
        Edit
      </button>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("Hello World!");

  return (
    <EditableComponent
      editMode={editMode}
      setEditMode={setEditMode}
      updateValue={setValue}
      value={value}
    />
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```